# Actual traffic level at given GeoPoint

Tags: android, google-maps, traffic

May I get actual traffic level at given GeoPoint using Google Maps API for Android? Now I am able to set traffic layer using

> mapView.setTraffic(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I get actual traffic level at given GeoPoint using Google Maps API for Android?

No, sorry.